# Set variable within a function as global: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var per = {Period: {"From":["W" + (moment().format('WW')-11)],"To":["W" + moment().format('WW')]}};;


var show = function (studios, platforms, vodest, sdhd, category, genre) {
var output = {
    Studios: studios,
    Platforms: platforms,
    VODEST: vodest,
    SDHD: sdhd,
    Category: category,
    Genre: genre
};


};
$.extend(output, per);
$('.list').html(JSON.stringify(output));
```

When i run the above code i get an error **ReferenceError: output is not defined** Is there a way i could the output variable as global and access it outside the function?

Comment: move the `var output` declaration out of the `show` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var per = {Period: {"From":["W" + (moment().format('WW')-11)],"To":["W" + moment().format('WW')]}};;

var output = {};
var show = function (studios, platforms, vodest, sdhd, category, genre) {
    output['Studios'] = studios,
    output['Platforms']= platforms,
    output['VODEST']= vodest,
    output['SDHD']= sdhd,
    output['Category']= category,
    output['Genre']= genre
};
$.extend(output, per);
$('.list').html(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: Tried this but doest help. The concatenation happens with the empty variable declared outside the function. The end result is `{"Period":{"From":["W10"],"To":["W21"]}}`

Comment: @  Tauseef Hussain you need to calling `show ();` before `$.extend(output, per);`

Comment: I made the below change and it worked perfect. Thank you for your help :)`var per = {Period: {"From":["W" + (moment().format('WW')-11)],"To":["W" + moment().format('WW')]}};;
var output = {};

var show = function (studios, platforms, vodest, sdhd, category, genre) {
    output['Studios'] = studios,
    output['Platforms']= platforms,
    output['VODEST']= vodest,
    output['SDHD']= sdhd,
    output['Category']= category,
    output['Genre']= genre

 $.extend(output, per);
    $('.list').html(JSON.stringify(output));
};`

Comment: @ Tauseef Hussain just and `show ();` before `$.extend(output, per)` and tell is it work?

Answer (score -1):

Try this trick :)

```
var per = {
    Period: {
        "From":["W" + (moment().format('WW')-11)],
        "To": ["W" + moment().format('WW')]
    }
};

function show (studios, platforms, vodest, sdhd, category, genre) {
    return {
    Studios: studios,
    Platforms: platforms,
    VODEST: vodest,
    SDHD: sdhd,
    Category: category,
    Genre: genre
    };
}

var output = show('s', 'p', 'v', 's', 'c', 'g');
output = $.extend(output, per);

$('.list').html(output);
```